# Number pad on wired apple keyboard isn't working with ElementaryOS

Tags: settings, keyboard

I have an Acer Swift 3 running Loki. I also have a wired Apple keyboard with a number pad connected to my laptop, and for some reason the numberpad doesn't register as numbers, but as directional arrows. Is there anyway to correct this? I checked the keyboard settings but couldn't find any solutions. The numberpad works on MacOS and Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That worked for me:

- get dconf-editor (from App store)
- go to

`org → gnome → settings-daemon → peripherals → keyboard`

- and change to
  `numlock-state on` (standard is "off")

Answer (score 0):

In `System Settings`, go to `Keyboard` and select the `Options` group along the top. On the left select `Miscellaneous compatibility options` and you will see several options for the keypad. You probably want to enable the top option to have it behave like macOS.

Comment: actually that doesn't include the numblock.